# How to check for offset in a loop

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I check for a offset in cake php in a loop?, I have a message saying this...

```
Notice (8): Undefined offset:  1 [APP\views\cars\car_details.ctp, line 53]

Notice (8): Undefined offset:  2 [APP\views\cars\car_details.ctp, line 53]
```

Its in a foreach loop and retrieving items like this

```
$car_ratings['CarRating'][$j]['reccar_num']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a check of [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) on the element like:

```
if(array_key_exists($j, $car_ratings['CarRating'])){
  // true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of the array (using `count()`) then don't go over it.

For example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($car_ratings['CarRating']); ++$i) {
    // use the array at $i
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to modify the loop, you can use `array_key_exists()` to determine if the array has a value defined for a particular key.

Of course using `foreach` would be better here.

If you could provide more context this answer might be better.